# Forge Viewer Autodesk

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I am new to forge and desperate. I have seen this example. How can I make the Forge Toolbar transparent as shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the picture you provided, the `light-theme` is used. 
You can set it like this: 
`viewer.setTheme('light-theme');` 
More info: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/dark-light-mode-viewer

The rest you can do by modifying the `style` of the various components. You can investigate in the browser's **Developer Console** what is being used by them:
[image]

From that you can see the you can simply add the following to your own **css** file to override the **background color** and **shadow** of those controls:

```
.adsk-viewing-viewer.light-theme .adsk-control-group {
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Here is the result: 
[image]

Comment: Hi Adam, wonderful it works...! :-)